# How do I go about installing a ground wire to a cordless drill converted to corded?

Tags: motor, grounding

I have a [RYOBI model HJP002 cordless drill](https://www.ryobitools.com/products/details/33287141791) purchased in 2010. Both 12 Volt batteries are dead and will no longer charge on the model C120D (140109001) charger that came with the drill kit.

[image: From linked website, shows 12V pistol-style drill driver from left-hand side]

In view of the high cost of replacement batteries, I decided to convert this drill, which I love for its variable-speed, forward-reverse, torque control, light weight and ergonomic design, from cordless to corded, following instructions of several U-tube videos on the Internet.

I purchased a model **S-180-12** AC-DC transformer and a surge protector for my wall outlet, removed one of the battery packs with its solid-state components board and have completed most of the other work for the conversion, except for determining how to connect a separate ground wire for safety.

While spending time researching the Internet for the answer to my subject question, I saw in [this article](https://www.integrasources.com/blog/bldc-motor-controller-design-principles/#:%7E:text=wye%20%28Y%29%20or%20star%20connection%20%28windings%20meet%20at,can%20protect%20the%20motor%20from%20overvoltage%20and%20overload) that a BLDC 3-phase motor was grounded through the circuit controller (MCU), employing Hall-effect sensors, but I don't know how to test my motor, using a VOM, to determine if it (the motor) is 3-phase, or 2-phase, or 1-phase.

Comment: It wasn't grounded to mains earth with the batteries. Why it should be now? What do mean by it should be connected for safety? Why is it suddenly unsafe now and how does earthing it makes it less unsafe?

Comment: A "starter set" of batteries and charger for Ryobi really isn't that expensive these days, especially around the holidays when Home Depot is running all sorts of sales. One of Ryobi's biggest selling points is that they haven't changed their battery form-factor since they started selling them a couple of decades ago, so the newest of batteries will work in the oldest of tools.

Comment: @FreeMan I just double-checked. As I suspected, this is the old 12-volt Ryobi. You can't (realistically) get batteries for it - this predates the 18-volt One+ system. It might even be the same as my first cordless drill. Is it worth all this trouble? Probably not. But then again, objectively speaking so many DIY projects are more about the challenge than about the results.

Comment: how many tabs does the battery have? It *might* have some battery management or some other thing.

Comment: If you're feeling brave, a 12V lithium battery pack probably has 3, 6, or 9 separate 18650 inside.   With care its possible to crack the pack open, and re-pack a battery with new cells inside.

Comment: @Justme the conversion changes it from safe 12v (hold both terminals without effect on a human) to less safe 110/240v [depending on location] and potentially lethal. The ground wire is to ensure that the RCD protection works correctly by providing a zero resistance path for live. However, it's not like there is much metal to go live in the device and most corded these days just rely on double-insulating everything along the voltage path, so a stray wire cannot make any external part live.

Comment: @simoncoleman The power supply is too big to fit into drill and it isolates, so the conversion does not change it to 120V/240V. Mains go to power supply. 12V goes to drill.

Comment: @Criggie that makes me feel old - my 12V drill was NiCd!

Comment: @justme The ground should just be as far as the AC reaches, ie, the transformer. If it is already double-isolated consumer grade then you can probably ignore it. If the transformer enclosure is metal then it must attach to that, as per DKNguyen's answer.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek In Li-ion things I've worked with, the extra tabs often only connect to the charger, not the device

Comment: @simoncoleman Exactly. The drill does not require earthing. The power supply requires earthing, and I never said it doesn't.

Comment: @ChrisH semi-related - I have an old-old ryobi drill at 7.2V ni-cad.  I gutted the battery and carved a hole in the side for a plsatic 18650 holder and glued that in.  Now the drill runs off 2 batteries in series, though its only good for light deburring etc.  A heavy load makes the batteries hot.   To recharge I have to pop batteries out and put them in a LiIon charger.  But it works !

Answer (score 20):

The whole point of the earth ground is so that if high voltage wires become loose and touch the case, the case doesn't become high voltage to shock anybody that touches it.

Your drill was never designed to operate with a high voltage inside it to begin with and therefore has no means for high voltage safety inside it that can be used. This means it has no conductive chassis to earth. Nor does it have double insulation to protect the user against loose high voltage wires inside when an earth ground is absent.

But none of that matters because there isn't any high voltage getting into your drill to begin with. Your AC-DC power supply is isolated (contains a transformer) and is a box sitting somewhere outside. That means high voltage isn't inside your drill and can't ever get inside your drill. The output side of the transformer is low voltage and its a transformer which means the high voltage input and low voltage output are isolated with nothing to fear from the low voltage side.

The only thing to fear is if they high voltage input wires happen to get loose. If your transformer is sitting in a metal box, then you earth that box. That's what the earthing is for. But if your isolated AC-DC power is just sitting out in the open then there's not much to do other than insulating the high voltage connections.

Answer (score 13):

Another answer already correctly covers most of the issues:

- The drill has no high voltage inside it
- The high voltage is all contained within the transformer/power supply, which outputs low voltage for your drill

However, if the [S-18012](https://amzn.to/489ePXm) is this Amazon product (or similar):

[image: 12V power supply]

then there are some additional issues to consider. This particular device does not appear to be properly certified for use in the US - e.g., UL or ETL certification. When used as a *component* in a commercial product that is much less of an issue as the entire product is what gets the certification. However, without any real certification there is a non-trivial concern as to whether this device is actually designed in a safe manner. Will any typical failure mode result in 120V AC ending up on the low-voltage output? What kind of overload protection does it have? What kind of overheating protection does it have? And so on.

In addition, even if this was a known good component - e.g., made by a major manufacturer and used "as is" inside UL or ETL listed appliances, you can't just use it by itself. It is clearly designed to be *inside* a larger device. Used separately, the possibility of debris getting inside the metal cage and shorting something out and the possibility of loose connections on the high and low-voltage sides, *which are right next to each other*, causing problems are very real concerns.

I would look for a UL or ETL listed *sealed* power supply with 12V DC output.

Comment: The UL mark for approved components is a funky backward UR, which can be seen at https://code-authorities.ul.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/ul_RecognizedComponentMarks.pdf - that is what a power supply _should_ have to be easily integrated into a product.

Comment: But if you do stick with that power supply or one that looks similar, secure your wiring so HV and LV can't come together, put the whole thing inside an earthed enclosure, add fuses... I've done it, but it's easier to get a sealed supply.  A 12V drill can also be run off a car battery with a couple of terminal clips - yes that's more like 13-14V but the drill won't care unless used continuously for ages.  Again, fit a fuse inline close to the battery

Comment: @ChrisH a 7.2V drill works really well at ~14V, and even works to turn a cutoff wheel for cutting wire rope off a winch.

Comment: An alternative to using an earth on the power supply is to double insulate it if the power supply is reliable enough.  Place it is a PLASTIC box with no exposed metal and with reliable cable strain relief and perhaps some additional robust  insulation barrier between the HV input and LV output.  The output is low voltage and does not require earthing.

Comment: @KalleMP yes, that's an option as well, however these power supplies are normally mean to be earthed for electrical (emissions) shielding as well as for safety.  And such a plastic box should be suitably robust. I've seen (and used, when I was young and poor) plastic storage crates for packaging mains projects.

Answer (score -2):

Connect one of the DC outputs of your power supply to the ground pin of your cord. Then, there will be no voltage in your drill different from ground by more than 12V (safe). This is commonly how low voltage DC equipment is wired.

Comment: Do you know if the power supply is isolated? Because if not and you pick the wrong lead, that's a nice way to blow it up.

Comment: @ChrisH Good point. Of course if it isn't, one lead is already grounded, and all is well. Any decent 21st century power supply has current limited outputs, so a blow up is unlikely.